# Delete parent row after moving (copying) child rows into another table

Tags: java, mysql

after moving child rows from one table to another and delete them from the first Table, I want to do the same with the parent rows but the foreign keys won't let me do that.

here's what I've tried :

```
INSERT INTO comptearchive SELECT * FROM compte WHERE idcompte = '3118';
INSERT INTO lignecomptearchive SELECT * FROM lignecompte WHERE idcompte = '3118';
DELETE FROM lignecompte WHERE idcompte = '3118';
INSERT INTO encaissementarchive SELECT * FROM encaissement WHERE idcompte = '3118';
DELETE FROM encaissement WHERE idcompte = '3118';
DELETE FROM compte WHERE idcompte = '3118';
```

Erreur SQL (1451) : Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bcpbdd3`.`encaissementarchive`, CONSTRAINT `encaissementarchive_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`idcompte`) REFERENCES `compte` (`idcompte`))

Comment: Then there are still rows somewhere which reference the parent row. Please [edit] your question to include the full error message you get. The error message will tell you what the problem is. Also, add the table structures (including the foreign keys) you have to your question, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query.

Comment: @Progman : I include the full error message. What I don't understand is since I move "compte" data to "compteArchive", the parent of "encaissement" will still exist, simply not in the same table...so why can't I delete the "compte" data?

Comment: Your archive foreign keys should reference the archive tables, but you are referencing the original `compte` table. Check clearly the table names you are using in "encaissementarchive_ibfk_1".

Comment: @Progman : I understand thatt so I guess my real question is : how can I make the foreign key   "encaissementarchive_ibfk_1" point to comptearchive table and not to original compte table?

Comment: Specify the correct foreign table when you create the table `encaissementarchive`. If you specify the table `compte` it will obviously use that table. You have to use the table `comptearchive` instead.

Comment: @Progman : my mistake,  I thought it was automatic...perfect ! thanks a lot !